# Why using service account from VM instance when listing BQ jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-compute-engine, service-accounts

I am trying to list the jobs running in big query for many projects using a user account which is having owner access on the gcp projects. We are using python APIs and all this process is running on a VM instance. But listing the job is failing because default service account for the VM instance doesn't have permission for other projects.

What I am unable to understand is, why using service account when the user have all the access. We don't want to create a service account with owner access, So is there anyway that we can list the BQ jobs only with our own account and not using service account.

This is the python code I am using for listing the job:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd

client = bigquery.Client(project=<project_ID>)
job_list = client.list_jobs(project=<project_ID>,max_results=100000, state_filter='running', all_users=True)
```

I tried giving the credentials with json file using below command, But that also was not helpful.

```
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json("0874ee00257b.json")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by default, the GCE instance (VM) is authenticated using the service account it has been given access to when it was created (default service account). That VM & service account is linked only to the project in which it has been created, and not to a user. This makes sense when you think about it. You wouldn't want VMs (or any services on GCP in fact) authenticated/tied to an individual user. This would be bad practice e.g. what is that user leaves the company and their account is deleted.

> So is there anyway that we can list the BQ jobs only with our own account and not using service account.

So, back to your actual question. Yes, but I wouldn't recommend doing this if it's something you intend to deploy and productionize/operationalize.

1. SSH into the VM
2. Run `gcloud auth login`
3. Follow the prompts

**Note**: when you do this, Google will even tell you it's not recommended and you should use service accounts instead:

[image]

Some more info here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing

Comment: Thanks for the response. First I got warning: WARNING: `gcloud auth login` no longer writes application default credentials. Then I tried "gcloud auth application-default login", and now it is working for me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Could you let me know, how to find the daily quota limits on user account. From Big query docs, I found only API rates per sec per user, But not the limit on daily basis. Here is the link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas. Thanks -